# Get data from Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning how to extract the source data from Internet Explorer. I have learned how to code it from YouTube. However, when I want to modify it to test another website, I encountered an error. Can anyone advise please?

Tested website: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com

```
Sub clickFormbutton()


Dim ie As Object
Dim form As Variant, button As Variant


Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


input1 = InputBox("Please enter keyword.")


With ie

.Visible = True
.navigate ("http://www.oxforddictionaries.com")


While ie.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend


ie.document.getelementsbyname("q").Item.innertext = input1


Set form = ie.document.getElementsbytagname("form")

Set button = form(0).onsubmit


form(0).submit


Do While ie.busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set TDelements = .document.getElementsbytagname("td")
r = 0
c = 0

For Each TDelement In TDelements
Sheet1.Range("A1").Offset(r, c).Value = TDelement.innertext
r = r + 1
Next





End With

Set ie = Nothing





End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell us  what the error is?  Please edit your question and include the error.

Comment: The error is Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you weren't very specific about the error you're receiving, it seems to me the first thing that is going to cause you a problem is the way you're using `getElementsByName()`.

`getElementsByName()` returns a *collection* of nodes having the specified `name` attribute value, in your case `name="q"`. For the page you're interfacing with, there are *two* nodes that contain `name="q"`, which you can verify with the following statement:

```
MsgBox ie.document.getElementsByName("q").length    ' => Reports "2"
```

The first node found seems to be a search box for *mobile* users. The second one is a search box for *desktop* users. So if you want to change the `innerText` of one of these nodes, you'll need to address a single node by index:

```
Dim e
Set e = ie.document.getElementsByName("q")(0)  ' Get first instance
Set e = ie.document.getElementsByName("q")(1)  ' Or, get second instance
e.innerText = "some text"
```

However, that brings us to your next problem. These elements are `<input>` elements, so setting `innerText` isn't going to do you any good. I'm guessing what you're trying to do is set their `value`, which you can do like so:

```
Set e = ie.document.getElementsByName("q")(1)  ' Get desktop search box
e.Value = "some text"
```